# jQuery .each not iterating through each

Tags: jquery, each

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I have the following jQuery. It is supposed to iterate through each `.box`, get the attribute 'fade' and apply the individual fade times to each `.box`. However, it ignores the `var fade` and just fades them all out at once. This doesn't necessarily have to be a fade, as I want to do several things to 'each' `.box`. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? and could you explain why? I really appreciate any help.

```
<div class="box" fade="1000"></div>
<div class="box" fade="3000"></div>
<div class="box" fade="6000"></div>
```

-

```
$('.box').each(function() {

   var fade = $(this).attr('fade');

   $(this).fadeOut(fade);

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your iteration is fine. But duration must be a number so typecast it to int:

```
$('.box').each(function() {

   var fade = $(this).attr('fade');
   $(this).fadeOut(+fade); //here 

});
```

Also fade is not a valid attribute consider using `data-fade` as the attribute name also accessing it with data api of jquery will automaticall cast it to number. Explicit cast is not needed in this case unlike accessing it with attr.

#### Markup

```
<div class="box" data-fade="1000">222</div>
<div class="box" data-fade="3000">333</div>
<div class="box" data-fade="6000">444</div>
```

#### JS

```
$(function(){
 $('.box').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var fade = $this.data('fade');
   $this.fadeOut(fade);

 });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q32zj/)**

Comment: @jcsanyi yes, using the data api.

Comment: Ahh - thank you, PSL. I wasn't aware of 'data-' attribute.  This solves one problem - but of course now I have another. But probably better for another question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @xtiaan That is used for the custom attributes like what you are doing so that your html remains valid.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does the leading plus sign turn a string into a integer?

Comment: @xtiaan Yes it is a unary operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators). You can also use `parseInt(fade,10)`

Answer (score 3):

`fade` is not a valid attribute. Switching them to `data-fade` works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/wJftm/

```
$('.box').each(function() {

   var fade = $(this).data('fade');

   $(this).fadeOut(fade);

});

<div class="box" data-fade="1000"></div>
<div class="box" data-fade="3000"></div>
<div class="box" data-fade="6000"></div>
```

Comment: Infact switching it to data-fade and accessing it using data api automatically type casts it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Tim. Appreciate it.